# How to develop label and textfield frame size both Xcode 4.3 and Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have developed the form in Xcode 4.5 ..

while i run the program using iPhone simulator 6.0 ,the label and textfield(more than 5 labels and textfields) is not properly aligned and the button is not shown in the simulator...

I run the same program but change the simulator hardware deveice Xcode 4 inch retina display,now its work good..

**What is problem and i need the solution.**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you do with your UI difficult to suggest anything. I guess you build UI in code, not in Interface Builder. If so, I could suggest have a look at autoresizesSubviews of you holder view and autoresizingMask of you UITextField and UILabel.

Comment: your UI looks different in different hardware simulators? Does your code change UI in some way?

Comment: only i used drag and drop label and text field in the .xib..i was not written any code for this..i was test the app two different kind of simulator(iPhone 3.5 inch retina display and iPhone 4 inch retina display)

Comment: Now its working..the problem is using auto layout... deselect auto layout(file inspector)

Comment: you can creating  all those labels and textfield through manually.

Comment: could you please answer your own question (write the fix into an answer). This would be great, since now this question is still set to unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: deselect auto layout(file inspector).This problem solved